# Custom header e.g. x-access-token is deleted by cloudflare

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, devops, cloudflare

Custom header e.g. x-access-token is deleted by cloudflare, as my node server required x-access-token in order to serve request.
This custom header is getting filtered by cloudflare, and I am getting the x-access-token header value as undefined.

I want whitelist the custom header - x-access-token , so that cloudflare don't drop it.